# In Azure, is it possible to move an existing set of hosted sites to another subscription?

Tags: azure

On Azure, I am currently using my "3-month Free Trial" subscription, and just recently I got access to a "Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Ultimate" subscription.

Is it possible to move an existing set of hosted sites to another subscription using the Portal?

Obviously I could just re-publish the sites using Visual Studio, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in the GUI?

Comment: I ended up contacting Azure Support, and they were very helpful.  They transitioned all of my services over to the new subscription.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way you can accomplish in the Portal interface. You do have an option to request Windows Azure Billing Team and request them move **all of your currently configured and running** services from one Subscription to other subscription, the key is "all".

IF you want to move one specific service from one subscription to another then the available option is to deploy directly to other subscription.

Comment: Thanks. I went this route and the Azure support team was great!

Comment: Do I have to create a billing ticket then even though it's not related to billing (not directly)

Comment: Due to the age of this just updating that this appears to still be true. I opened a ticket related to account subscriptions and they stated the most important key things are that you must migrate all services under the source subscription and that the destination subscription should be new/empty.

Comment: Is this still the state of things 4 years later?

Comment: 5 years later... yes it is :/

Answer (score 1):

I did do this once. I had to contact their billing team and after a couple of days of back and forth between them it was taking too long so I just did it manually, redeploying the sites to the new subscription. This may not be possible if you have many sites. I did a backup and restore of the SQL Azure database.

Answer (score 1):

I am battling with azure support right now on trying to do the same thing.  From what I can tell your best bet is creating the services on your MSDN subscription and redeploying.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know a way to do this from the portal but I do recommend using [Windows Azure PowerShell](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools) which has the ability to manage multiple subscriptions and in your case you can just do this cmdlet to copy a service into another subscription:

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject -sn MyNewSubscriptionName
```

Comment: Where am I calling this from?